# I can only add a record to my database for one time why?

Tags: c#, database, lookup

I'm trying to do add record to my database with my c# project.

I can add a record for only one time. The next time I'm trying to add new record I got an exception.

Why does that happen? I didn't change any code. Here is the code:

```
try
{
    connect.Open();
    cmd.Connection = connect;

    using (cmd = connect.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [kalorivediyet].[dbo].[Uyeler](kullaniciadi,sifre,mailadresi,cinsiyet,boy,kilo,yaş,kalori) VALUES('" + txtkullanıcıadı.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtsifre.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtmail.Text.Trim() + "','" + selectedcmbox.ToString() + "'," + int.Parse(txtboy.Text) + "," + float.Parse(txtkilo.Text) + "," + int.Parse(txtyas.Text) + "," + kalorii + ")";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Baglanti Kurulamadı Lütfen Tekrar Deneyin");
    connect.Close();
}
finally
{
    connect.Close();
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get? Don't use string concatenation  but sql parameters, always. Also, show us the schema of your table, what columns does it have and which types? What is the primary key, do you have any constraints, f.e. a [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190024.aspx) on any column(s)?

Comment: Please tell us your exception message! You probably have defined some unique key constraints that are violated when you try to add the same record again. And btw: your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com/). If this is just for experimenting, it's ok, but you should always use parameterized queries, even if it's just for practising.

Comment: I have primary key it's kullaniciadi(username) and I don't put the same username again I don't have another unique key I'm doing this code try catch and when it try to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery it is going to catch

Comment: @alidurgun Please, what you _catch_ is an _exception_. This _exception_ has at least a _`Message`_ that tells you _what_ went wrong. Please show us this message.

Comment: There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: I have kalori column and it would be decimal and I did decimal (5,2) in database

Comment: I also tried float(20) for kalori but it's nothing

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if you are violating some of the constraints in the database scheme? I mean, unique values, primary_keys and so on... I think that this is the reason.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is rather a comment than an answer. As long as OP does not tell us what kind of exception he gets or the structure of his table we can only guess.

Comment: But I can not put comments with this reputation

Comment: I know. You need to gain a little reputation first by posting good answers before you can comment. That's a StackOverflow restriction. One can discuss about if this is good or not, but anyway, posting comments as answers is not a good way. I'm sure you will gain the necessary reputation soon.